# Feeds and PHP 7.0

Tags: 7, feeds

I am using Drupal 7 on Ubuntu 16, Apache 2.4.20, and PHP 7.0.9.

When attempting to use a Feed importer on PHP 7.0, I receive a 500 AJAX Error that gives no Response Text.

[image]

Additionally, nothing is shown in the error logs.

However, when switching my Apache PHP version back to 5.6, it works just fine.

Is there any support for Feeds on PHP 7.0 this yet? Or should I stay away from PHP 7 for a while?

Comment: looks to me that you should be reporting this into the module's [issue reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/feeds?text=php+7&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All)

Comment: I am using feeds with PHP 7 with no issues. Maybe your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Did you had a look at your PHP error log, to see if there is a more detail message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I reported this issue and found the solution.

The issue was the feeds tamper module. Updating from Feeds Tamper version 7.x-1.1 to 7.x-1.x-dev solved the issue.

So if you are using PHP 7.0, I recommend using Feeds version 7.x-2.0-beta2 and Feeds Tamper 7.x-1.x-dev.

Here is a link to the issue I opened:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2790355#comment-11571211

I hope this helps others with this situation.